# Login and password iOS issue(chrome)

Tags: ios, angular, google-chrome

I can't get data from a login form using JS after autofill. It looks like the browser does not emit events and JS can't see the data. I'm using Angular, by the way.

Only after I change this data manually, can JS see it:

> [image: Manual data changes]